# When flying Singapore->Kuala Lumpur->Penang, where is immigration cleared?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, malaysia, kul

I ask because I'm booking separate tickets and am assessing the required connection time.

Will I need to go through immigration in Kuala Lumpur before heading to the gate for the KUL-PEN flight?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when changing between an international and a domestic flight, passport control will take place at the connection airport, in this case KUL.

Luggage will be checked through, however, except in a few countries (not including Malaysia AFAIK)